# Reaction of weak alkali and strong acid

Tags: acid-base

How the alkali molecules can dissociate completely in the reaction of weak alkali and strong acid?

Comment: Welcome to Chem SE. I'm not exactly what you're trying to ask. Could you clarify a bit more?